# Optimizing clustering in Python

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, cluster-analysis

I wrote my own clustering algorithm (bad, I know) for my problem. It works well, but could work faster.

Algorithm takes list of values (1D) as in input, and works like this:

1. For each cluster, calculate distance to closest neighbor cluster
2. Select the cluster A which has smallest distance to neighbor B
3. If distance between A and B is less then threshold, **return**
4. Combine A and B
5. Goto 1.

I probably reinvented a wheel here..

This is my brute foce code, how to make it faster? I've Scipy and Numpy installed, if there's something ready made

```
#cluster center as simple average value
def cluster_center(cluster):
  return sum(cluster) / len(cluster)

#Distance between clusters
def cluster_distance(a, b):
  return abs(cluster_center(a) - cluster_center(b))

while True:
  cluster_distances = []

  #If nothing to cluster, ready
  if len(clusters) < 2:
    break

  #Go thru all clusters, calculate shortest distance to neighbor  
  for cluster in clusters:
    cluster_distances.append((cluster, sorted([(cluster_distance(cluster, c), c) for c in clusters if c != cluster])[0]))

  #Find out closest pair 
  cluster_distances.sort(cmp=lambda a,b:cmp(a[1], b[1]))

  #Check if distance is under threshold 15
  if cluster_distances[0][1][0] < 15:
     a = cluster_distances[0][0]
     b = cluster_distances[0][1][1]
     #Combine clusters (combine lists)
     a.extend(b)

     #Form a new cluster list
     clusters = [c[0] for c in cluster_distances if c[0] != b]
  else:
    break
```

Comment: I wouldn't know where to begin, but luckily someone else might: https://code.google.com/p/scipy-cluster/ and http://glowingpython.blogspot.com/2012/04/k-means-clustering-with-scipy.html

Comment: K-means clustering requires knowledge of number of clusters, and with scipy-cluster I don't know where to begin :)

Comment: Did you reinvent agglomerative clustering? Have a look at: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#hierarchical-clustering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, the term "cluster analysis" is only used for *multi-variate* partitions. Because in 1d, you can actually *sort* your data, and solve much of these problems much easier this way.

So to speed up your approach, **sort your data**! And reconsider what you then need to do.

As for a more advanced method: do kernel density estimation, and look for local minima as splitting points.

Comment: Yes, data is sorted.  Could you explain what's "kernel density estimation"?

Comment: Look it up in your favorite math/statistics book. Or Wikipedia.